# how to change website background using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i have an issue changeing the background , it always show or change the background only if the image id =1 , how can i dysplay other values ?

here is my php code :

```
<?php
include "config.php"; //Database connection file
//Check the database for background color
$check_page_color = mysql_query("select * from `page_color` where `id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string('1')."'"); // where `id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string('1')."'
if(mysql_num_rows($check_page_color) > 1) //If no color is found, use the default color below > 1
{
$page_color = "#F9F9F9"; //Default Color
}
else
{
    $get_page_color = mysql_fetch_array($check_page_color);
    $page_color = strip_tags($get_page_color["background_color"]); //Color from the database
}
?>
```

CSS :

```
<style type="text/css">

body {  
background-image: url(<?php echo $page_color; ?>);
</style>
```

and here is the HTML code that displays the photos :

```
New Background:<select name="img" class="vpb_field" id="color" style="height: 40px; width: 151px" >
                <option><?php echo $page_color; ?></option>
            </select>
<span class="vpb_general_button" onclick="vpb_submit_form();">Submit</span>
```

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($check_page_color) > 1) should be less than 1 for no rows

Comment: Please look at View Source ... on the offending page and tell us exactly what is showing up in your CSS when PHP is done with it.

Comment: you want change bg color or image? because i see $page_color = "#F9F9F9";  but css expect image background-image

Comment: I found a way which is bit more advance, i guess. Turn your .css file to .php file. That way you can create a function to change background colour.

`style.css` to `style.php`

Inside it you can create something like

`<?php
$colour = 'gray';
?>

body {
  background: <?php echo $colour; ?>;
}`

Comment: Also add `header("Content-type: text/css"); ` inside `<?php //inside ?>`.

Comment: Can you show the body tag on html ?? and also order in which PHP, CSS and html code placed inside the file ??

Comment: i dont know whats wrong , if i changed the <select> </select> to normal text area and type the name of the photo manualy rather than chosing from select it works , so whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you taking 1 id in mysql you can take all with while and add them in a string[] and again you can make new while on option for all color options

```
<?php $page_color = mysql_query("select * from `page_color`"); 
  $counter = 0;
  $i = 0;
  while($showall = mysql_fetch_array($page_color))
        {
        extract($showall);//<-- we cut your data hire
        $counter++;
        $array_colors[] = $color; // <-- This is your mysql col
        ?>
        <select name="img" class="vpb_field" id="color" style="height: 40px; width: 151px" >
       <?php while($i < $counter) // <-- You can change this if u want size_of     
         {echo '<option>'. $array_colors[$i] .'</option>';}
         ?>
        </select>
```

this will give you all options now ucan use your other html code

Comment: This doesn't really explain how to solve it properly. It would help if you updated the answer with a code example.

Comment: It explains as if there is multiple options in db you can make it select option tab to display other colors, so he can surf inside other colors.